# Rust: combine select! with FuturesUnordered.buffered(N)

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am using `FuturesUnordered` to enqueue async workloads onto a multi-threaded tokio runner. These futures return various different kinds of results. To differentiate them, I map each future's result to a custom `Event` type.

```rust
enum Event {
   ResultTypeA {...},
   ResultTypeB {...},
   ResultTypeC {...},
   ResultTypeD {...}
}

let pending_futures: FuturesUnordered<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Event> + Send>>> = FuturesUnordered::default()

loop {
    tokio::select! {
        Some(future) = workload_receiver.recv() => {
            pending_futures.push(future.boxed());
        },
        Some(event) = pending_futures.next() => process_event(event),
        else => break,
   }
}
```

Above code works well, however, I would like to limit the number of pending_futures to process in parallel. This is where `buffered_unordered` comes in. My naive approach was:

```rust
loop {
    tokio::select! {
        Some(future) = workload_receiver.recv() => {
            pending_futures.push(future.boxed());
        },
        Some(event) = pending_futures.buffered(10).next() => process_event(event),
        else => break,
   }
}
```

This throws the following compilation error:

```
    --> src/main.rs
     |
257  |     Some(event) = pending_futures.buffered(10).next() => process_event(event),
     |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Event` is not a future
     |
     = help: the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `Event`
     = note: Event must be a future or must implement `IntoFuture` to be awaited
note: required by a bound in `buffered`
    --> futures-util-0.3.24/src/stream/stream/mod.rs:1359:21
     |
1359 |         Self::Item: Future,
     |                     ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `buffered`
```

How can I limit `FuturesUnordered` to only ever process N futures of its underlying queue at the same time but still allow dynamically enqueuing new futures?

Comment: Error is obvious but even if you had solve that problem, `buffered`  takes the ownership of the `pending_futures`, this means you'll not be able to enqueue new ones(since you will not have access the `pending_futures`). Instead you may create buffered(or unbounded) channel over `workload_receiver` or separate queue to feed `pending_futures`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use `FuturesUnordered` if you want to limit the concurrency, it will run all of the contained tasks, all the time. Using `.buffered()` won't help with that since the `Stream` that it implements is for the results of the tasks, after they've completed.

If your `workload_receiver` is a `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver`, then you're in luck! You can convert it directly into a `Stream` via [`ReceiverStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/wrappers/struct.ReceiverStream.html) from the [tokio-stream](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/index.html) crate (wrappers for other things exist as well). This will work perfectly with `.buffered()` or `.buffered_unordered()` since the items you appear to be receiving are `Future`s.